# problem in setting autotext programmatically

Tags: android

I want to set the autotext programmatically, I have set the edittext property like

`EditTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE);` but no effect.

Please give some inputs

Answer (score -1):

the method equivalent to android:autotext is [setKeyListener(KeyListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener%28android.text.method.KeyListener%29)

Comment: That is not an equivalent method. If you read the link, this is a similar method.